How to show time added by user in the signup page
I am working on the profile of the user and I need the time he added in the sign up page of the work hours daily to appear on his profile . I created a time range picker and I don't know how to make it show up here . Here it's the code from sign up page  with time
 DirectSelect(
                      itemExtent: 50.0,
                      selectedIndex: selectedIndex1,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.white30,
                      child: MySelectionItem(
                        isForList: false,
                        title: elements1[selectedIndex1],
                      ),
                      onSelectedItemChanged: (index) {
                        setState(() {
                          selectedIndex1 = index!;
                        });
                      },
                      items: _buildItems1()),
                  const SizedBox(height: 15.0),
                  ButtonTheme(
                    minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.93,
                    height: 60,
                    child: TextButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                        TimeRange result = await showTimeRangePicker(
                          context: context,
                          onStartChange: (value) {
                            setState(() {
                              selectedIndex2 = value.hour;
                            });
                          },
                          onEndChange: (value) {
                            setState(() {
                              selectedIndex3 = value.hour;
                            });
                          },
                        );
                      },
                      child: Text(
                          'Select work time (${selectedIndex2} AM - ${selectedIndex3} PM)'),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 10),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () async {
                      if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                        final translator = GoogleTranslator();
                        await translator
                            .translate(country, to: 'en')
                            .then((value) {
                          country = value.text;
                          print(country);
                        });
                        Map<String, dynamic> data = {
                          'address': controller.text,
                          'country': country,
                          'disabled': false,
                        };
                        DocumentReference reference = FirebaseFirestore.instance
                            .collection('Users')
                            .doc("$userId");

                        FirebaseFirestore.instance
                            .runTransaction((transaction) async {
                          transaction.update(reference, data);
                        });

                        FirebaseFirestore.instance
                            .collection('dusers')
                            .doc(userId)
                            .set({});

                        FirebaseFirestore.instance
                            .collection('Users/$userId/BusinessAccount')
                            .doc('detail')
                            .set({
                          'category': elements1[selectedIndex1],
                        }, SetOptions(merge: true)).catchError((e) {
                          print(e);
                        });
                        FirebaseFirestore.instance
                            .collection('${elements1[selectedIndex1]}')
                            .doc('$userId')
                            .set({
                          'id': '$userId',
                          'categoryName': elements1[selectedIndex1],
                          'openTime': elements2[selectedIndex2],
                          'closeTime': elements2[selectedIndex3],
                          'address': controller.text,
                          'country': country,
                        }, SetOptions(merge: true)).catchError((e) {
                          print(e);
                        });

                        FirebaseFirestore.instance
                            .collection('Homepage SuperUser')
                            .doc('$userId')
                            .set({
                          'user': '$userId',
                          'expired_on': DateTime.now()
                              .add(const Duration(days: 7))
                              .millisecondsSinceEpoch,
                          'plan': 'free',
                          'notified': false,
                          'expired': false,
                        });

                        FirebaseFirestore.instance
                            .collection('Category SuperUser')
                            .doc('$userId')
                            .set({
                          'user': '$userId',
                          'expired_on': DateTime.now()
                              .subtract(const Duration(days: 7))
                              .millisecondsSinceEpoch,
                          'plan': 'free',
                          'notified': true,
                          'expired': true,
                        });

                        print(DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days: 7)));

                        Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (_) => const Homepage()));
                      }

and here I created a Row with a calendar icon where I want to appear the time he added each user in the signup page
   Row(
                                children: [
                                  Icon(Icons.calendar_month,
                                      color: Colors.grey, size: 18)
                                ],
                              ),

